# TailwindCSS Carousel Responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am working with Tailwind CSS Carousel and having a responsiveness problem.

The Carousel is appearing fine on all devices except on mobile devices, whenever the screen is becoming smaller the image in the carousel is being cropped rather than getting smaller in dimension:

```
 <div className=" h-1/2 w-full relative group">
      <div
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slides[currentIndex].url})` }}
        className="h-5/6 bg-cover duration-500 overflow-hidden"
      ></div>
      {/* Left Arrow */}
      <div className="hidden group-hover:block absolute top-[50%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] left-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer">
        <BsChevronCompactLeft onClick={prevSlide} size={30} />
      </div>
      {/* Right Arrow */}
      <div className="hidden group-hover:block absolute top-[50%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] right-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer">
        <BsChevronCompactRight onClick={nextSlide} size={30} />
      </div>
      <div className="flex top-4 justify-center py-2">
        {slides.map((slide, slideIndex) => (
          <div
            key={slideIndex}
            onClick={() => goToSlide(slideIndex)}
            className="text-2xl cursor-pointer"
          >
            <RxDotFilled />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `background-size: contain;` so the image gets smaller along with the screen size.

Here's an example comparing `cover` and `contain` values for background size in CSS:

```css
.div1{
  background:no-repeat url('https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/53e1d1414b5bab14f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e5074417c2f7dd4944ac5_640.jpg');
  background-size:contain ;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  border:5px solid green;
}
.div2{
  background:no-repeat url('https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/53e1d1414b5bab14f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e5074417c2f7dd4944ac5_640.jpg');
  background-size:cover ;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  border:5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class='div1'>
</div>
<br/>

<div class='div2'>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is being responsive thanks. However, the carousel container is not. I mean the image becomes smaller but the controls and indicators position still the same.

Comment: Could you show me a picture?